# Select folders which start with a perticular string in c#

Tags: c#, search, windows-forms-designer, directory, checkedlistbox

I have many folders(around 300)  that start with the same name,how do I display only those folders that start with a specific string in my checked list box instead of displaying all the folders in the checked list box(its annoying to search through 300 files to find the desired files)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can use StartsWith method like this

```
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories("YourPath",
                    "*.*",
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f=> f.StartsWith("YourSharedFolderName"))
                    .ToList();
```

Hope this help.

Comment: does not contain a definition for 'where' and no extension method 'where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)How do i resolve this ?

Comment: You need to add System.Linq to the using section, also can you give more details about why do you think it doesn't work ?

Comment: when i tried to debug it ,that line was skiped.All the otherlines where executed

Comment: Which line ? do you mean f=> f.StartsWith... one ? Tell me about what results do you get ? you should get all the directories names that starts with "YourSharedFolderName" string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Contains()` method to solve the problem

> Returns a value indicating whether a specified substring occurs within this string.

See the given example. here I assume your folders are stored as `String`

```
    List<String> folders = new List<string>(); // Assume your folders contai inside a List<>

    // Example with dummy data
    folders.Add("Testfolder1");
    folders.Add("Myfolder2");
    folders.Add("Testfolder3");
    folders.Add("Bestfolder4");
    folders.Add("Okayfolder8");

    // iterate through the List and extract folder names with certain string
    foreach (String item in folders)
    {
        if (item.Contains("Test"))
        {
            // Will only extract names which contains string Test
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

Note that `Contains()` is case sensitive. So for cases you need case insensitive search you might be interested in `String.ToUpper()` OR `String.ToLower()` methods.